# Downloading data via WinInet

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

And so there is a code, that can download data with size not higher than 1024*100 bytes. Code brought from https://rsdn.org/article/inet/inetapi.xml.

As far as I understand, `InternetReadFile` after every call should move on the read characters count, or it's sensless, because it'll return the same data. I red, that there is a function,that moves reading start pointer. Have I to use it?

```
HINTERNET hInternetSession;
HINTERNET hURL;
char cBuffer[1024*100];            // I'm only going to access 1K of info.
BOOL bResult;
DWORD dwBytesRead;

// Make internet connection.
hInternetSession = InternetOpen(
    L"tes", // agent
    INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,  // access
    NULL, NULL, 0);                // defaults

// Make connection to desired page.
hURL = InternetOpenUrl(
    hInternetSession,                       // session handle
    L"https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",  // URL to access
    NULL, 0, 0, 0);                         // defaults

// Read page into memory buffer.
while(bResult = InternetReadFile(
    hURL,              // handle to URL
    (LPSTR)cBuffer,    // pointer to buffer
    (DWORD)1024 * 100,       // size of buffer
    &dwBytesRead)==TRUE&&dwBytesRead>0) // pointer to var to hold return value

// Close down connections.
InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
InternetCloseHandle(hInternetSession);

DWORD dwTemp;
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile) {
    return 0;
}
WriteFile(hFile, cBuffer, sizeof(cBuffer), &dwTemp, NULL);
```

**Issue: I can't read more than 1024*1024 bytes, program crashes, when creates char[1024*1024]**

Comment: `char[1024*1024]` - are this is local variable in function ?

Comment: @RbMm, yeah, it`s all are local

Comment: so what you want - stack size by default 1Mb - this array eat all stack and as result stack overflow

Comment: @RbMm, well I want to load data with size bigher than 100 kb

Comment: and in what problem here ?

Comment: @RbMm i dont`t understand how can I copy it to memory buffer, with help of I can write to local storage

Comment: why you want copy all data to single buffer ? create local storage **before** begin download. and when you receive **chunk**  of data - just write it to local file and so on (and `cBuffer, sizeof(cBuffer)` - of course error - you need write actual number of bytes received, but not buffer size). if you need by some reason too big buffer - in what problem allocate it from heap or via VirtualAlloc ?

Comment: @RbMm, You mean, I should make a loop, where i call IReadFile, and then WriteFile? To WriteFile i have to receive number of bits, that i got from IReadFile?

Comment: for example and this. why not ?

Comment: @RbMm, well, making `char cBuffer` global solved the issue. I didn't know about the stack as well. Now, as far as I undestood the stack for local is 1 mb, and for global equals 2 gb. Thanks for that

Comment: *making char cBuffer global solved the issue* - really say only about you low skills in topic. from where you know file size at begin ? what if it will be large that your hardcoded size buffer ?

Comment: @RbMm, but does `WriteFile` wouldn't rewrite already wroted data? Maybe I should use `cout`?

Comment: *stack for .. global equals 2 gb* - really ? ) about *WriteFile wouldn't rewrite already wroted data* - you need at begin learn more about file io

Comment: @RbMm, I didn`t say that I have high skills. File size, that I need in my program is regular

Comment: @RbMm there https://www.viva64.com/ru/k/0036/ was wrote, that the stack for 32bit and for 64 bit is 2gb for global static data

Comment: *2gb for global static data* - absolute nonsense. global data not use stack at all

Comment: you need be able work with data chunks. and learn more how WriteFile work - at which offset you wrote data

Comment: @RbMm, create 1024-bytes chunks, and wrote via cout to file, while `dwBytesRead > 0`, I've tried this, but it wrotes only 920 bytes, as far as I remember. But ok, I'll try again

Comment: *via cout to file* ?!

Comment: @RbMm, oh, I'm sorry, it's just a language difficults, You kwon) I mean `ofstream` )

Comment: you need use `WriteFile` but not ofstream

Comment: @RbMm, why not ofstream? I've watched a lot of examples with ofstream. But, as I know, the `>>` operator read until gets the space character

Comment: but anyway finally will be called WriteFile and NtWriteFile - so why not call it direct yourself ?

Comment: why not `WriteFile(hFile, cBuffer, dwBytesRead, &dwTemp, NULL);` ?

Comment: @RbMm, oh yes, agree, I will use it

Comment: @RbMm, ok I'll try this one `WriteFile(hFile, cBuffer, dwBytesRead, &dwTemp, NULL);`

Comment: @RbMm, all works good. Thank You very much, and sorry for stupidity)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete program. Thanks to @RbMm

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"wininet")


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
HINTERNET hInternetSession;
HINTERNET hURL;
            // I'm only going to access 1K of info.
BOOL bResult;
DWORD dwBytesRead=1;

// Make internet connection.
hInternetSession = InternetOpen(
    L"tes", // agent
    INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,  // access
    NULL, NULL, 0);                // defaults

// Make connection to desired page.
hURL = InternetOpenUrl(
    hInternetSession,                       // session handle
    L"http://wallpapers-images.ru/1920x1080/nature/wallpapers/wallpapers-nature-1.jpg",  // URL to access
    NULL, 0, 0, 0);                         // defaults

// Read page into memory buffer.

char buf[1024];

DWORD dwTemp;
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"пример.jpg", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile) {
    return 0;
}

for (;dwBytesRead>0;)
{
    InternetReadFile(hURL, buf, (DWORD)sizeof(buf), &dwBytesRead);
    WriteFile(hFile, buf, dwBytesRead, &dwTemp, NULL);
}

// Close down connections.
InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
InternetCloseHandle(hInternetSession);

CloseHandle(hFile);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `sizeof(buf)` in call `InternetReadFile` instead `(DWORD)1023` (why not 1024 ?). you not need zero init buffer at begin `buf[1024] = {};` for what ?! and always check return values of `InternetReadFile` and `WriteFile` for break loop on error

Comment: @RbMm, ok, I`ll change it

Comment: simply do `while ( InternetReadFile(..,&dwBytesRead) && dwBytesRead && WriteFile(..,dwBytesRead,..) ) ;`

Comment: @RbMm this style of writing is uncomfortable for me

Comment: @RbMm Not a good style. Better check each functions return value individually so we know which function failed.